# Why did English take the "mix pronunciations and spellings" route instead of one rule route like French, or separate languages/dialects like Spanish?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, history, pronunciation-vs-spelling

Like the multiple pronunciations of "ough" or different spellings for the same sounds in English I've read come from mixing different dialects into one language. Whereas with French, they imposed on centralized set of rules. Or in Spanish, there are multiple languages/dialects in Spain (though I think at least Franco did try to impose Castellano for all). And other countries have their own histories of language homo/heterogeneity routes taken.

What made English turn out the way it did, as opposed to others?

In other words, did England ever try to impose one set of rules on how to say written letter combinations (e.g. 'ough'), like other languages have done, one way or another?

Comment: In French, *ô*, *au*, *aux*, *eau*, *eaux*, *haut*, *hauts*, *ho*, and *aulx* are all pronounced the same. Maybe you shouldn't complain quite as much about "different spellings for the same sounds." (In French, it is true that if you know the spelling of a word, you have a pretty good guess at how it's pronounced.)

Comment: I think you're missing the point and only proving my example. Are those words you gave each pronounced differently? Or always the same way?

Comment: FYI talking about how language works is not complaining. If you think that, why are you here.

Comment: These words are all pronounced exactly the same.

Comment: You're not understanding me. Is aux ever pronounced differently?

Comment: I assumed that by "different spellings for the same sounds" you were talking about the way *fined* and *find* or *pair, pare, pear* are pronounced the same. But you seem to have meant "different sounds for the same spelling," which isn't the same thing at all.

Comment: I think you'll find variations in the way that French and Spanish are pronounced across the world, just as with English.

Comment: @Peter Shor I said both of those things

Comment: German is quite easy to pronounce from its spelling. But if you are from Lithuania, your German pronunciation might not be the same.

Comment: @Weather Vane I'm really talking about in their respective countries. And generally, there are different accents for spanish and french, but they usually follow the same rules. Spanish is said how you read it, and french has rules. Even quebec sends languages tests to france.

Comment: I'm asking about the history of the formation of the languages in their countries.

Comment: @Peter Shor My question is more about the imposing or a set of rules, or keeping languages separate, or not. In countries' histories. That question brings up where the differences came from, but I'm asking why England didn't then impose one rule, or keep things separate, like France or Spain, and rather just left things as a mix.

Comment: It is a bit complicated to answer. We can simply say that English speaking people decided to keep their language more flexible or "democratic", and adopt foreign words more freely. However, there can be many factors like the divergence of American English, and spreading of English language to many areas, as well as regions. Then, perhaps, it was too late to tame this beast.

Comment: Yes if it's too complicated to answer, that may be an answer. But yeah, it's probably not a simple question.

Comment: As comments reveal and experience tells us, the question is based on an over-simplification of phonemic orthography and on consequent unjustifiable assertions about various languages.  As such a simplification it cannot be answered reasonably within the bounds of this site. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonemic_orthography  The question should be closed.

Comment: English like European Spanish (and Italian and German and probably every other language) has multiple dialects with different spellings (although some, e.g. Catalan, are separate languages and others like Luxembourgish or modern Scots are debatable). But I don't really see what that has to do with whether the spelling is phonetic/consistent/logical. You'd be better off reading books, or at least the Wikipedia articles on the respective languages, and come back once you have a better understanding and a more specific question.

Comment: Y'all are not understanding the question. No, Spanish and French do not have different pronunciations of the same written text, though they may come out in different accents. Spain has 5 languages,  Catalan is a separate language. Spanish you also write how you say it. French has variations, but how you say it is consistent,  also in Spanish. English is a mix, both how you write and say it. The question of why England mixed stuff rather than impose one set of rules or leave them separate was not answered before. Ppl should let ppl answer questions ppl wanna answer and stop trolling lol

Comment: Nobody is trolling you. I don't think there is any way to answer your question except 'that's the way it is'. English is a mixture of Celtic, Scandinavian and Latin words and has evolved piecemeal.

Comment: There is history to look into. My point is it clearly wasn't answered before. I could rephrase it as, did England try to impose one rule or keep languages separate. That might be easier to focus on.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you talking about borrowings from foreign languages into a target language? Considering dialects is just complicating things - name the languages you care about. Also, is this just about spelling, or simply forcing phonology of a target language on the foreign borrowing? In any case, you should give explicit examples (words with pronunciations). For potential close voters, it is totally on topic here to compare English with other languages.

Comment: I'm asking if english has ever tried to impose one set of rules or have tried to keep different influences as separate languages. Like France or Spain

Comment: People understood the question. For example, why didn't english try to impose one pronunciation for 'ough', one way or another, simple as that.

Comment: Something very similar ***was*** answered before [Why English pronunciation differs so much from written language, compared to German?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1071/why-english-pronunciation-differs-so-much-from-written-language-compared-to-ger/412043#412043), but more people voted to close it for lack of details than as being a duplicate, so it's not being closed as a duplicate. But why doesn't that answer your question?

Comment: For the record, my confusion comes from 'mixed pronunciation'. Sure there is the well-known awfully chaotic correspondence between spelling and pronunciation in English, so I imagined the OP is about something about loanwords like 'valet' /va le/ in French, but /va let/ in English (BrE; AmE drops the t). If the question is about the general 'why the chaos?' then this is as gen ref/duploicate as can be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that English spelling has not been kept up to date. It was more regular (although not standardized) in Middle English.

Also, the standardization of English spelling did not occur in a very systematic manner. [Samuel Johnson’s dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Dictionary_of_the_English_Language#Criticism), while an impressive accomplishment, was the work of one man and its spellings did not always follow consistent principles. As the linked article mentions, the spellings followed in Johnson's dictionary often were based on a principle of trying to bring the spelling of an English word close to the spelling of the Latin root that was thought to be related to it, but since not all English vocabulary is from Latin, this principle cannot be applied to all words.

[Spanish spelling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_orthography), in contrast, has undergone reform more frequently, more systematically, and more recently.

Comment: I don't think English spelling has been regular since Old English.

Comment: Excellent concise answer that will not be appreciated by the OP (who has left). Minor quibble... Johnson was the manager and primary writer but he had six assistants, so it was not the 'work of one man'.